# Sed to replace lower case string between two strings to upper case

Tags: regex, bash, sed

i have a text file as below. I want to change the lower string between `foo` and `var` to upper case.

```
foo nsqlnqnsslkqn var
lnlnl.
foo DkqdQ HNOQii var
```

my expected output is

```
foo NSQLNQNSSLKQN var
lnllnl.
foo DKQDQ HNOQII var
```

i have used a one liner using sed `sed 's/\(\foo\).*\(\var\)/\U\1\2/' testfile.txt`
but i get the following output

```
FOOVAR
lnlnl.
FOOVAR
```

Comment: Look at your `sed` expression and try to observe the various capture groups and you might be able to figure the output you get!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `\U` to make something become upper case:

```
$ sed 's/.*/\U&/' <<< "hello"
HELLO
```

And `\E` to stop the conversion:

```
$ sed -r 's/(..)(..)(.)/\U\1\E\2\U\3/' <<< "hello"
HEllO
```

---

In your case, just catch the blocks and place those `\U` and `\E` accordingly:

```
$ sed -r 's/(foo )(.*)( var)/\1\U\2\E\3/' file
foo NSQLNQNSSLKQN var
lnlnl.
foo DKQDQ HNOQII var
```

- `(foo )(.*)( var)` catches three blocks: `foo`, the next text and `var`.
- `\1\U\2\E\3` prints them back, upcasing (is it a verb?) the second one (`\U`) and using the current case (`\E`) for the 3rd.

Without `-r`, to make it more similar to your current approach:

```
sed 's/\(foo \)\(.*\)\( var\)/\1\U\2\E\3/' file
```

So you can see that you were not catching the `.*` block, so you were printing back just `foo` and `var`.

---

From [the manual of sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command):

> **\L** Turn the replacement to lowercase until a \U or \E is found,
>
> **\l** Turn the next character to lowercase,
>
> **\U** Turn the replacement to uppercase until a \L or \E is found,
>
> **\u** Turn the next character to uppercase,
>
> **\E** Stop case conversion started by \L or \U.